# Exporting variables to application scope in meteor with coffeescript, but still having it available in package scope

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor, meteorite

I'm working on a package, written in coffeescript, that will end up exporting a variable to application scope using `api.export`(IE I want this variable to accessible throughout any application where this package is installed). [This site](http://shiggyenterprises.wordpress.com/2013/09/09/meteor-packages-in-coffeescript-0-6-5/) makes the following statements (quote):

> - Plain root level symbols are file-scoped, i.e. not visible in other files of the package
> - Symbols starting with @ are package globals, i.e. visible in all files of the package.
> - Exported symbols are visible in all files of the package and in the application code. But must not start with a @-character.

However, I want to append some things to this variable before I export it to application scope, and these operations need to occur in separate files. To solve this, I was trying to create a package scope variable, modify that, then create a variable on the file-scope that is an alias for the same object, and export this variable. This way, I can edit in package scope, but I'll still have my exported variable in the application scope.

To simulate this, I created [this small git repository](https://github.com/BloodChiefStromberg/coffee-package) with three classes: Base, ClientDeriv, and ServerDeriv. Base is located in the `lib` directory, and `ClientDeriv` and `ServerDeriv` are located in the `client` and `server` directories respectively.

**lib/Base.coffee** (see the edit: this file has been updated slightly)

```
class @CoffeePackageHandle.Base #this should create a package level variable with this class attatched
 constructor: (@isBase) ->
   return true

CoffeePackageHandle = @CoffeePackageHandle #this is a file scope variable, but we'll use api.export
                                           #make this available in the final app
```

**client/client-deriv.coffee**

```
class @CoffeePackageHandle.ClientDeriv extends @CoffeePackageHandle.Base
  constructor: (@catchPhrase) ->
    return "I'm on the client, I'm a giant!"
```

**server/server-deriv.coffee**

```
class ServerDeriv extends CoffeePackageHandle.Base
  constructor: (@catchprhase) ->
    return "I'm on the server, I like hamburgers!"
```

**package.js**

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Test of making packages with coffeescript!"
});

Package.on_use(function(api, where) {
  api.use('coffeescript', ['client', 'server']);
  api.add_files([
    'lib/base.coffee',
    'client/client-deriv.coffee',
    'server/server-deriv.coffee'],
    ['client', 'server']);
  api.export('Coffee-Package-Handle', ['client', 'server']);
});
```

The application almost starts, but then I get the following error (no longer get this, see edit below):

```
W20140421-14:56:29.607(-4)? (STDERR)
W20140421-14:56:29.611(-4)? (STDERR) /home/AD/arst238/coffee-package/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:186
W20140421-14:56:29.613(-4)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20140421-14:56:29.613(-4)? (STDERR)    ^
W20140421-14:56:29.622(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot set property 'Base' of undefined
W20140421-14:56:29.623(-4)? (STDERR)     at lib/base.coffee:1:27
W20140421-14:56:29.623(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/base.coffee.js:16:3
W20140421-14:56:29.623(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/AD/arst238/coffee-package/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140421-14:56:29.624(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140421-14:56:29.625(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/AD/arst238/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140421-14:56:29.625(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/AD/arst238/coffee-package/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

This is a simple test package, but in my actual package I often run into this error as well (which was appearing in this simple test package as well for a while):

```
W20140421-14:28:48.330(-4)? (STDERR) /home/AD/arst238/coffee-package/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:186
W20140421-14:28:48.331(-4)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20140421-14:28:48.332(-4)? (STDERR)    ^
W20140421-14:28:48.332(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'describe'
W20140421-14:28:48.333(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/package.js:1:44
W20140421-14:28:48.335(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/package.js:14:3
W20140421-14:28:48.336(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/AD/arst238/coffee-package/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140421-14:28:48.336(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140421-14:28:48.336(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/AD/arst238/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140421-14:28:48.337(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/AD/arst238/coffee-package/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing to incur either of these errors, or why sometimes I'll get one instead of the other. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I may have resolved the first error, but that resolution leaves me still getting the second error (the `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'describe'`) one. The solution was adding the line
`@CoffeePackageHandle = {}`
to the beginning of `lib/base`. Then, if `package.js` is removed from the project, the application compiles and launches properly. With `package.js`, I am still getting the second error. The repository will be changed to reflect these changes.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're exporting the name `Coffee-Package-Handle` instead of `CoffeePackageHandle`?

Comment: Nope! But that actually wasn't my error (actually, that may have been the cause of the first error). I was running the package as if it was an app (total brain fart), which was obviously not working. But besides what you mentioned, and what I just mentioned, everything works!

Comment: Oh I see. FWIW, I came up with a slightly different solution to the problem. See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281235/coffeescript-namespace-exports-in-meteor-custom-packages).

Comment: Recommend you answer your own question if you think it's helpful to others, or delete it if it's not.