# CoffeeScript namespace exports in Meteor custom packages

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

For a few hours, I couldn't get my Meteor package to export variables defined in CoffeeScript files.

In `foo.coffee`, for example, I tried using `@Foo = {foo: 1}`, `Foo = {foo: 1}`, `exports.Foo = {foo: 1}`, and so on and so forth, but *nothing* would work.

Finally, after looking at the Meteor [coffeescript test package on github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/coffeescript-test-helper/package.js), I placed the `api.export();` call *before* the `api.on_use()` call for that package **and it worked**.

#### Any idea why?

My package is set up as follows:

#### Directory

```
foo/
    .meteor/
    .build/
    foo.coffee
    package.js
```

#### foo.coffee

```
class FooBar
  constructor: ->

Foo =
  FooBar: FooBar
```

#### package.js

```
Package.describe({
    summary: "A package that makes foo with foobar"
});

Package.on_use(function(api) {
    api.use("coffeescript", "client");
    api.export("Foo", "client"); // <-- Moved this to *before* the on_use declaration

    api.add_files("foo.coffee", "client");

});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Coffeescript compiles

```
@Foo =
  FooBar: FooBar
```

to

```
(function() {
  this.Foo = { 
    FooBar: FooBar
  };  
}).call(this);
```

You need to remove the `this.` before `Foo`, take a look at [namespace](http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing), but it's not a good idea since you might need to compile it once you modify the original coffee files.

Here's my trick:

Add a file, named `global_variables.js`:

```
Foo = this.Foo;
```

Then add it in your package.js:

```
api.add_files('xxx', 'xxx', 'global_variables.js');
```

Then it just works!

Comment: +1 for the global definition file. I agree, I'd like to avoid editing the coffeescript files after compiling them. I wonder if there's a clean way to monkeypatch Meteor's builtin `coffeescript` package...

Comment: Incidentally, I'm perfectly happy with using the `api.export` call to declare variables _before_ `api.add_files` (as outlined in my question). I was really just curious as to why this works.

Comment: I prefer adding the `Foo = this.Foo;` to the top of the package.js

Answer (score 1):

Another plain & simple solution:

lib/namespace.coffee

```
Users = {} # This is a local variable
@Users = Users # Globalize your variable
```

package.js

```
api.addFiles('lib/namespace.coffee');
api.export('Users');
```