# how to export variables from coffeescript in meteor packages

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I'm confused by how to use exported variables with coffeescript meteor packages.

[edit] concrete example.
I followed various advice and have a JS file `_defines.js`

```
//defines.js
Ribot = {}
```

Then

```
# server.coffee

Meteor.startup ->
  Ribot = new Bot()

Meteor.methods botReply: (obj) ->
  reply = Ribot.reply("user", obj.text)
```

so the problem is that the Ribot object within the startup block is not available inside the meteor methods block.

When i write similar code with javascript:

```
Meteor.startup( function() {
  Ribot = new Bot();

Meteor.methods({
  botReply: function(obj) {
    reply = Ribot.reply("user", obj.text)
```

things work fine.

the current hack to get around is define everything to hang off a `share.Ribot` as per meteor's coffeescript support.

So for step one I don't actually need to export the Ribot object outside the package since most of the interface is currently via Meteor.methods, however I will need to eventually.

---

details below

[There are more complicated suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281235/coffeescript-namespace-exports-in-meteor-custom-packages), but I found that what works in a package is the opposite of normal CS app development.

eg:

```
Rbot = {}   # no @ on declaration

Meteor.startup ->
  @RBot = new Thing()    # use @ in references
  console.log("new Rbot", @RBot)
```

and then in package.js

```
api.export(['RBot']);
```

it's now available to the app.

However, in normal coffeescript usage from within my app (not a package) the opposite is true. For example

```
# use @ when declaring
@SceneData = new Meteor.Collection("SceneData")

Meteor.startup ->
  if Meteor.isServer
    Meteor.publish "SceneData", (query, fields) ->
      # dont use @ when referencing
      return SceneData.find(query, fields)
```

This also seems different than how normal coffeescript works outside of meteor (see ex below).

Within the app i think this is maybe because meteor is calling methods with a "this" object the same as the top level window? So there's another layer of "magic" going on?
Whereas within a package Meteor is wrapping more closures than coffeescript itself.

If someone can suggest the "right" way to do this, or explain why these two opposite wrapping/@ref styles are needed in the same framework, that'd be enlightening.

compiler example:

```
@outer = "outer"
inner = "inner"

p1 = () ->
  console.log @outer   # wont run
  console.log(outer)

p2 = () ->
  console.log inner
  console.log @inner

p3 = () =>
  console.log @outer
  console.log(outer)


p1()
p2()
p3()

// compiles to:

(function() {
  var inner, p1, p2, p3;

  this.outer = "outer";

  inner = "inner";

  p1 = function() {
    console.log(this.outer);
    return console.log(outer);
  };

  p2 = function() {
    console.log(inner);
    return console.log(this.inner);
  };

  p3 = (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      console.log(_this.outer);
      return console.log(outer);
    };
  })(this);

  p1();

  p2();

  p3();

}).call(this);
```

Comment: The package method allows you to export variables *without attaching them to the global object*. This means that Meteor can expose the variable to a package that depends on it, while hiding it from other packages and/or the application code. This means packages, whether written in JS or CS, do not pollute the global namespace unless they are directly depended on by the application.

Comment: but `api.export(['RBot']);` is meant to make your toplevel package desired exports available to the app. but in many cases it can't find an already defined RBot to reference when exporting, so it just provides RBot = undefined in the app's (global) namespace.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused. What do you mean it can't find an already defined variable when you export it? As you said in the beginning of your post, you need the `api.export` line and you need to declare the variable in your code. But `api.export` does not automatically expose a variable to an application's global scope. Consider an application which depends on package A, which depends on package B. The application code will only be able to see package A's exports, which will be attached to the global object. It can not see package B's exports because it only indirectly depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `@myVariable = value` in a package, you don't need to export `myVariable` since there's no *package variable* named `myVariable`, because you have instead attached it as a new property to the global object. However, you should avoid doing this, since packages shouldn't modify the global object, but exporting some of its package variables instead.

However, package variables must be defined as global variables (in JavaScript: `myVariable = value` (and **not** `var myVariable = value`), and the downside is that there's no equivalent statement in CoffeeScript (in CoffeeScript `myVariable = value` compiles to `var myVariable = value`, which creates a file scoped variable). To solve this, the meteor folks introduced the `shared` variable (containing an object), and the idea is that package scoped variable should be assigned as properties to this object. Read more about it in [the docs for CoffeeScript in Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/coffeescript).